# ¿Cómo puedo extraer la funcionalidad de transaccionar un fragmento en un object Util?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, supportmapfragment

He creado el objeto **Util**, para poder llamar a sus funciones desde cualquier clase.
Dentro de este objeto, he creado la función **openFragment** para poder llamar a la transicción del fragmento desde cualquier lugar, pero me está dando un error de "Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager" en la linea en la que declaro la variables **transaction**.

**Object Util**

```
object Util {

     fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment, container : Int) {

        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        transaction.replace(container, fragment)

        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class HomeView : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPrincipalViewBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityPrincipalViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        //Fragment by defect in activity Home
        Util.openFragment(DaysUntilView(),R.id.flHomeContainer)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`supportFragmentManager` es un método de la clase `FragmentActivity`. En tu activity puedes usarlo porque extiende de la clase `AppCompatActivity` que es una subclase de `FragmentActivity`.

Entonces para usarlo en tu objeto `Util` necesitas agregar un parámetro de tipo `FragmentActivity` (o una subclase de esta).

Puedes hacerlo explícitamente:

```
fun openFragment(activity: FragmentActivity, fragment: Fragment, container : Int) {
    val transaction = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ...
}
```

o implícitamente usando [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions)

```
fun FragmentActivity.openFragment(fragment: Fragment, container : Int) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ...
}
```

De está forma la invocación se ve mas limpia y no necesita escribir `Util.`

```
openFragment(DaysUntilView(), R.id.flHomeContainer)
```

De hecho lo ideal sería que no exista un objeto `Util` sino que las funciones estén declaradas en el top level. Como menciona la documentación:

> Kotlin functions can be declared at the top level in a file, meaning
> you do not need to create a class to hold a function ...

Per ten presente que lo que estás haciendo no es recomendable. En vez de hacer transacciones manualmente deberías usar el [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started). En la misma documentación del `FragmentManager` te dice que no lo uses:

> We strongly recommend using the Navigation library to manage your
> app's navigation. The framework follows best practices for working
> with fragments, the back stack, and the fragment manager.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, tienes razón en todo lo que me comentas. Sobre el punto de utilizar **navigation componente**, en la pregunta se me olvido incluir que el desarrollo era para un **bottom navigation view**. No se si se puede utilizar el navigation component, pero todos los ejemplos que encontré eran con el método que puse en el ejemplo de la pregunta. Un saludo!

Comment: Claro que se puede, hay un ejemplo en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation). También hay ejemplos en [codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#8) y [videos](https://youtu.be/28kAFPvJ5lA?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-vin7SvgoaR6wu24sAw-sE).

Comment: Tienes razón! Acabo de conseguir implementar Navigation a un bottom navigation view con la documentación que me has facilitado. Mil gracias por la ayuda! :)